# pktgen-dpdk !PANIC!: *** Did not find any ports to use ***

Tags: dpdk

i am trying to start pktgen but it seems it does not see the interfaces i bind since it give me

```
!PANIC!: *** Did not find any ports to use ***
```

setup info: i have this issue on ubuntu 20.4 and redhat 8.3

```
dpdk version= DPDK 20.11.0
ena verison =2.1.0K
pktgen-20.11.3
```

i launch with those configurations:

```
pktgen -l 0-3 -n 3 -- -P -m "[1:2].0, [2:3].1"
```

note: i have 4 cores and 0 is not to be used so i send through core 1 and receive through core 2 for port o and i send through core 2 and receive through core 3 on port 1. is that a wrong configuration?

for the interfaces here is the status of the two interfaces i bind:

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:00:06.0 'Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) ec20' drv=vfio-pci unused=ena
0000:00:07.0 'Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) ec20' drv=vfio-pci unused=ena

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:00:05.0 'Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) ec20' if=eth0 drv=ena unused=vfio-pci *Active*

No 'Baseband' devices detected
==============================

No 'Crypto' devices detected
============================

No 'Eventdev' devices detected
==============================

No 'Mempool' devices detected
=============================

No 'Compress' devices detected
==============================

No 'Misc (rawdev)' devices detected
===================================

No 'Regex' devices detected
===========================
```

so i guess i did bind the interface correctly. so what am i missing ?? any help

Comment: looks like the dpdk library is not identifying the `ENA` port, please use the argument `--log-level=pmd,8 -w 0000:00:06.0 -w 0000:00:07.0` and re-run the pktgen application. Share the logs by updating the ticket. Note: Always share DPKD version, OS version, Firmware of NIC, Pktgen version. I am not marking the ticket as `missing details` yet, so please update with necessary information ASAP.

Comment: where it will store the logs where to look?

Comment: If you have run with the arguments what I shared, the logs will be displayed n the console

Comment: nothing displayed. https://pastebin.com/i9LEBRuv

Comment: incorrect assessment it did display relevant details `!PANIC!: *** Did not find any ports to use ***
PANIC in pktgen_config_ports():
*** Did not find any ports to use ***`. Looks like you really do not have a port on PCIe `0000:00:06.0`

Comment: that info is show with and without the --log-level. but how come it does not see adapter on 0000:00:06.0

Comment: what does this mean 0000:00:06.0 'Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) ec20' drv=vfio-pci unused=ena
and why it does not see it

Comment: i guess it is an issue with pkt-gen since i did run testpmd and it recognizes the ports as seen here https://pastebin.com/W4WtXMnw.

Comment: only reason why your pktgen is not able to probe `06:00.0 and 07:00.0` is because pktgen is built with DPDK libraries which did not have `ENA` built into it. So check your DPDK build and rebuild pktgen by ensuring in `$RTETARGET/lib` has `ENA` PMD

Comment: owh is there any documentation on how to do this. thank you

Comment: I have already shared to list the directory and check. Let me explain again, I assume you have $RTE_SDK and $RTE_TARGET set. If yes then `ls $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/lib | grep ena`. This will show you the `librte_pmd_ena`. If this is shared library, then you are missing a key argument in pktgen to make i work. So please share.

Comment: waiting for your updates

Comment: thx for your reply i really appreciate it. when i did compile dpdk i used meson and ninja so i didnt need to export the RTE variables but i understand what you ask for and i didnt find any so file that is named as librte_pmd_ena here is the list of what i found https://pastebin.com/cH3X2Jxs. when i search for in find i get https://pastebin.com/Giydxsez. what is interesting was i was able to lunch pktgen on redhat using the binary in Builddir/app but i still have issues with ubuntu

Comment: for redhat to be working i had to export the location of the libdpdk.pc file in pkg_config

Comment: hmm  if you are using `libdpdk.pc`, then it is shared library. Can you confirm the same ASAP?

Comment: I have shared the cause for no ports. Try it out and accept (and upvote) the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using with meson or ninja for building DPDK it generates both static libraries and shared libraries. But `pkg-config --cflags --libs libdpdk.pc` returns the shared library for linking.

So when built with shared library mode for any DPDK application, one has

1. `either` modify Makefile to enable linking with PMD (librte_pmd_ena.so) explicitly for the constructor to work
2. `or` mention the desired library as DPDK argument `-d librte_pmd_ena.so`

based on the comment update, it looks like you are using shared library build. Since you are not passing with option `-d` the PMD constructor does not invoke `probe` for `ENA PMD`. So please fix this by passing `-d librte_pmd_ena.so` in pktgen cmdline.

Comment: i couldnt find the librte_pmd_ena.so and since it work on redhat and this file does not exist so i speculate they change the name or so. any way i try with this file and it works librte_net_ena.so.21.0. and finally thank you very much :)

Comment: thank you for confirming the shared libraries were used to build DPDK pktgen. There should had been linux soft link for `librte_net_ena.so to librte_net_ena.so.21.0`